# Нестандартный поиск по таблице MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

Есть поле в таблице 'category'. Внутри него номера категорий, у определенного id, что то в роде:

```
//2,5,12,26,31
```

если искать скажем категорию 3, то при использовании LIKE - будет найдены все записи у которых есть цифра 3, но не обязательно 3 в списке. Найдутся и 13, и 31 и т.д.

Есть конечно решение вопроса, сделать категории такими:

```
//100002,100005,100012,100026,100031
```

Тогда при поиске 100003, я найду 100003, и не факт что я когда то добью категории до 1100003, и найду эту категорию в месте с 100003

Надеюсь на понимание.. Вопрос: можно ли при запросе к таблице, к полю среди 2,5,12,26,31 - найти определенное значение, допустим 3, и что бы не было найдено значений типа 13 и 31 ?

Comment: Улыбнуло до неприличия приветствие автора: "Приветствую всех вошедших" :)

Comment: Изначально у вас проблема в построении логике БД. Что мешало создать отдельную таблицу с //2,5,12,26,31 ?

Comment: Я так постоянно всех приветствую ))

С учетом ответа @Андрей Толмачевский, @Johny - как минимум отдельная таблица не нужна (будет медленнее работать, и менее удобно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where 'category' like '3,%' or 'category' like '%,3,%' or 'category' like '%,3'
```

Оговорюсь что с mysql я работал не особо много и возможно есть более быстрое решение этой задачи. Второй вариант решения этой задачи - создание в контексте mysql функцию, которая переводит такую строку в набор значений и дальнейшее использование оператора IN с этой функцией.

Еще как вариант использовать регулярное выражение:

```
WHERE 'category' REGEXP '(^3,)|(,3,)|(,3$)'
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот любите вы заморачиваться с изобретением велосипедов, вместо того, чтобы [справку](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html) полистать...

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, `category`)
```

Comment: ха! Первый раз вижу такую команду. У себя в бд все записи разбил по первой форме, и использую GROUP BY.. во я дурак 8-)

может кто написать, эта команда по скорости как? по идее mysql будет каждую запись перебирать

Comment: Если возникнут сомнения в скорости работы, то просто добавляйте запятую в начало и конец данных:  

    ,12,14,1,
Тогда при поиске:  

    ,1,
Вы всегда найдете то, что надо.

Comment: Если строка будет начинаться с запятой, то ``FIND_IN_SET()`` отвалится.

"Правильнее" всего сделать поле типа ``SET``, и перечислить заранее все возможные категории. А при обновлении категорий делать ``ALTER`` полю.

При таком поиске ``FIND_IN_SET()`` будет выполняться побитово и выигрыш в скорости будет в 100500 раз больше.

Comment: Я имел ввиду так:  

    LIKE *,1,*

Comment: @ReinRaus, я вас понял. В любом случае поиск значения в ENUM или SET будет значительно быстрее, нежели в полях других типов. Вы со мной не согласны?

Answer (score 2):

1. Почитайте про [нормальные](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) [формы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129195/) и постарайтесь переделать сруктуру таблиц в соответствии с ними.
2. Если по каким-то причинам реструктуризация таблиц невозможна, попробуйте такое условие:

   ```
   where numbers like '%,{id}' or numbers like '{id},%' or numbers like '%,{id},%'
   ```

`{id}` нужно заменить на нужное вам число. Сработает только если меджу числами и запятыми нет пробелов.