# Сложный поиск в поле таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших.

Собственно есть база с товарами, типа:

```
// id | articul | razmer | color | ves | cena | nalichie
```

Бывает что у одного артикула несколько размеров, у одного размера несколько цветов, у одного цвета несколько 'весов' (развый вес) , ну и от всего этого разная цена и по каждой записи разное наличие

```
155 | 1234-1234567 | 15 | red  | 25 | 500 | 20
156 | 1234-1234567 | 15 | blue | 25 | 550 | 15
157 | 1234-1234567 | 15 | red  | 35 | 600 | 10
159 | 1234-1234567 | 16 | red  | 25 | 400 | 18
160 | 1234-1234567 | 16 | blue | 25 | 350 | 17
164 | 1234-1234567 | 16 | red  | 35 | 200 | 80
166 | 1234-1234567 | 17 | red  | 25 | 500 | 55
168 | 1234-1234568 | 15 | red  | 15 | 900 | 11
180 | 1234-1234568 | 15 | gren | 85 | 990 | 22
200 | 1234-1234568 | 18 | blue | 95 | 950 |  0
```

т.е. 1 артикул, и к нему много модификаций. Как хранить и использовать это в бд? Ну первый вариант GROUP BY - и в процессе поиска все будет удобно найти. Но если все объединить? Как искать?  ( немного похоже на [вчерашнюю тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248009/php-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-mysql) )

```
//допустим в итоге хочется видеть, что то в роде:
id  | articul      | combine
101 | 1234-1234567 | "15:red:25:500:20","15:blue:25:550:15","16:red:35:600:10"...
102 | 1234-1234568 | "15:green:85:990:22","18:blue:95:950:0"
```

- можно ли как то использовать разные условия поиска по ним? Допустим найти размер только 15, при цене меньше 800, или цвет только red, при кол-ве больше 0 ?
- рационально ли так делать? (в плане скорости работы бд)

Comment: Посмотрите http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0 . При проектировании иногда сознательно идут на денормализацию для ускорения работы, но это решение принимается для каждого конкретного случая с учётом различных факторов (которых Вы не приводите). Идеологически правильнее -- нормализовать.

Comment: @alexlz, так да, нормализовать то у меня сделано, в место red/blue - 1/2. Вопрос уже дальше, вот допустим перестрою я структуру на ту, что описал, и не представляю можно ли с ней работать будет

Comment: @frank

       нормализовать то у меня сделано, в место red/blue - 1/2

Извините, а причём тут нормализация? Ну а вариант 

       102 | 1234-1234568 | "15:green:85:990:22","18:blue:95:950:0"

-- из серии "можно ли сделать ещё хуже? -- давайте попробуем!"

Comment: @frank Конкретнее структуру таблиц и какой запрос.

Comment: @frank, если Вы спрашиваете про запрос

    найти размер только 15, при цене меньше 800, или цвет только red, при кол-ве больше 0 ?

для таблицы

    id  | articul      | combine

то средствами только SQL (т.е. на стороне базы) не получится.

Comment: вот как я описал в первом посте, допустим запрос к полю 'combine' -> нужно найти цену < 800, при цвет = blue, кол-во > 0 т.е. среди нагромождения вроде

    "15:green:85:990:22","18:blue:95:950:0".. //такого
    15:green:85:990:22,18:blue:95:950:0...... //или такого (думал посоветуете)

    нужно как то выбрать - WHERE 'combine' ЧУДО_КОМАНДА "%:=blue:%:%:>0"
    или (если записывать без кавычек) - WHERE 'combine' ЧУДО_КОМАНДА %:=blue:%:%:>0

т.е. в ссылке на тему которую дал - там четкий поиск по определенному значению, а вот если добавить несколько условий, и не просто '=' , а '=,>,<'

Comment: У одного артикула не может быть несколько чего то там. Артикул это ведь и есть уникальный идентификатор товара, разве нет?

Comment: Задайте вопрос лучше так: когда останутся только идеальные заказчики? .. или когда каждый будет счастлив.. ну а артикул он не уникален, по крайней мере в том проекте с которым разбираюсь я

Comment: @frank, в принципе наверное можно написать такую процедуру на PL/SQL и передавать в нее аргументы запроса, в т.ч. 

    %:=blue:%:%:>0

вот такие.

Только вот эффективно работать не будет. По сути в такой PL/SQL процедуре придется весь поиск  для  %:=blue:%:%:>0 делать вручную. 

Представьте, что всю эту мутоту Вы программируете на ПХП, получив результат 

    select * from table where articul = ...

такого запроса.