# Как изменить 'LIKE %1%', чтобы ограничить выборку числом, а не цифрой?

Tags: mysql, sql, like

В mysql-таблице с пользователями есть поле organizations, в котором через запятую перечисляются целочисленные ID групп. Но запрос с `WHERE organizations LIKE %1%` будет отдавать всех, в чьём ID групп есть хотя бы одна единица. Как можно модернизировать запрос, чтобы не отдавать лишнего? Если это невозможно, надо менять идентификаторы групп?

Comment: незнаю работают ли в mysql скобки, если да то так: `like '[0-9]'` или так `like '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: можно регуляркой

Comment: Вот прямо как по ссылке выше. `find_in_set`. И коментарий в том ответе, что так хранить данные в реляционных БД _нельзя никогда_, вашего вопроса то же касается.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Нашёл [решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248009/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-mysql) уже после публикации. И, конечно, вы правы, надо сделать key-value таблицу.

Comment: @СергейПанов  Ну то решение совсем кривое, если уж like то тогда хотя бы concat(',', organizations, ',') like '%,1,%' по крайней мере без дурацких OR